# How to create checkbox or radio button of custom layout type in android

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, radio-button, android-custom-view

want to create checkbox or radio button with custom layout similar to the below attached picture.
I have searched different sites but only able to find a way by changing background selector state.
but I need something like the below picture:

[image]

Comment: its not a check box its grid view and in adapter you can mange the selected item color or background color

Comment: RadioGroup and RadiaButton could do it , but have to overwrite some method in RadioGroup .  Use RecyclerView is more simple

Comment: @Anna can you answer with some snippet code for radio button?